# populate returns empty query mongoose

Tags: mongoose, populate

I have the following schema in mongoose, with User, Team and Clubs.

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String, 
        required: true
    }, 
    phonenumber: {
        type: String
    }, 
    team: 
        {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Team'}
    club: 
        {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Club'},
});



const clubSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String, 
        required: true
    }, 
    clublogo: { type:String }

});


const teamSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String, 
        required: true
    },  
    club: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Club',
    },
    image: { type:String },

});
```

I'm trying to populate the User table, with the club and the team, but i'm having some troubles with it.
when I run the following query it works fine:

```
    User.find().exec(function(err, users) {{
        if(users) {
            var userMap = {};
            users.forEach(function(user) {
                userMap[user._id] = user;
            });
        
            res.send(userMap);  
            }  else { res.send({});}
        });
```

But when I try to use populate to get 'team' data in user, it returns empty object  (also tried without specifying the model)

```
User.find({}).populate([{path:'team',model:'Team'}]).exec(function(err, users) {
            if(users) {
            var userMap = {};
            users.forEach(function(user) {
                userMap[user._id] = user;
            });
        
            res.send(userMap);  
            }  else { res.send({});}
        });
```

any ideas why?

Comment: mongoose version ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works for me.

```
User.find({}).populate(
    'team',
    'name club image'
);
```